# How to get the path of the faces which are stored in the android device

Tags: android, face-detection

I am working on Face detection application in android.

I want to know the path where the native android will store the faces after detecting the face by using front facing camera.

I tried searching by using all keywords but I am not able to find.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The faces will be stored as hashes, not as images. Also it will be impossible to get the files without root access.

Comment: Even with Root this isn't possible. It would be a **HUGE** security issue if it was.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, But why down vote?

Comment: What evidence do you have that faces get stored anywhere?

Comment: @CommonsWare When user purchase new phone he will register his finger print or face to unlock his device, When next time user comes to unlock they need to use the registered fingerprint or face. That means they need to store it some where in the device.

Answer (score 0):

"Face detection" as a term is usually reserved for identifying faces in a photo. What you are describing ("When user purchase new phone he will register his finger print or face to unlock his device") is biometrics.

Biometric data [is not accessible to apps](https://source.android.com/security/biometric#hal-implementation), by design.

Comment: I will capture face from front camera and I want to compare that face to access my application, what should I do?

Comment: @NagarajuV: If you want to use the device's own biometrics, use `BiometricPrompt` to authenticate the current user. If you want to roll your own face-recognition stuff, that's outside of my area of expertise.